# Plotting CIRES data in python

Tags: python, netcdf

I'm using the 20th century reanalysis mean sea level pressure data (CIRES), and I'm trying to make a plot of Hurricane Sandy. (I have used matlab, but for class I have to use Python and seem to be missing elements)

My Code so far is this:

```
    import netCDF4 as nc
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pylab as plt
    import datetime as dt
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

    def read_var(ncfile, varname):
      fid= nc.Dataset(ncfile, 'r')
      out = fid.variables[varname][:]
      fid.close()
      return out

    psl = read_var('prmsl.2012.nc', 'prmsl')
    lat = read_var('prmsl.2012.nc', 'lat')
    lon = read_var('prmsl.2012.nc', 'lon')

    def prmsltime_from_datetime(wanted_dt):
      time0 = dt.datetime(1800, 01, 01)
      prmsltime = (wanted_dt - time0).days*24
      return prmsltime

    date_i_want = dt.datetime(2012, 10, 28, 0) 
    print prmsltime_from_datetime(date_i_want)

    avg = np.min(psl[1204:1208,34:19,28:41], axis=0)
    print avg

    lat1= lat[np.where(lat >= 24)]
    mylat=  lat1[np.where(lat1 <= 52)]
    lon1 = lon[np.where(lon >= 54)]
    mylon=  360 - lon1[np.where(lon1 <= 86)]

    lons, lats = np.meshgrid(mylon,mylat)
    m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=24,urcrnrlat=52,llcrnrlon=274,urcrnrlon=306,resolution='c')
    plt.figure()
    x,y=m(lons,lats)
    plt.contourf(x,y, avg)
    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.colorbar()
    plt.xlabel('Latitude')
    plt.ylabel('Longitude') 
    plt.title('SLP on October 28, 2012')
    plt.show()
```

However when I print time, I receive an answer in the millions so I believe this is screwing up my data plotting since when I plot the 28th of october nothing of the likes of a hurricane shows up . ANY HELP MUCH APPRECIATED!!!

Comment: Will this error be easily reproducible without appropriate input files?

Comment: I'm not sure, probably not though

Comment: It's not clear to me where your time is being used.. Your `prmsltime_from_datetime(date_i_want)` is returning 1865568, which is indeed the number of hours from Jan 1 1800 to Oct 28 2012. But it's not clear to me where (if at all) date is taken into account in subsequent code.

Comment: first after initializing my date that I want, I have in the line avg = np.min(psl[1204:1208,34:19,28:41], axis=0)   the 1204:1208 which is the time index. 2012 was a leap year so 366 days with 4 hourly wind data. So the 1204 is oct. 28. Do I need to have datetime within the data somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You have almost got it, but not quite there...

You have to figure out the indices to use.

To use `prmsltime_from_datetime()` to get the time for 2012-10-28 0000hrs UTC, then look up the `time` array for the index:

```
time = read_var('prmsl.2012.nc', 'time')

date_i_want = dt.datetime(2012, 10, 28, 0)
t           = prmsltime_from_datetime(date_i_want)
t_idx       = np.where(time == t)[0][0]
```

Also for the data:

```
lat_top    = np.where(lat <= 52)[0][0]
lat_bottom = np.where(lat >= 24)[0][-1]
lats       = lat[lat_top:lat_bottom]

lon_left   = np.where(lon >= 274)[0][0]
lon_right  = np.where(lon <= 306)[0][-1]
lons       = lon[lon_left:lon_right]
```

Then you can define the map boundaries with these co-ords.

```
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',
            llcrnrlat=lats[-1], urcrnrlat=lats[0],
            llcrnrlon=lons[0], urcrnrlon=lons[-1],
            resolution='c')
```

Obtain the data, create a mesh for the x and y points and finally plot it.

```
# convert to mb
data = 0.01*psl[t_idx, lat_top:lat_bottom, lon_left:lon_right]
x, y = m(*np.meshgrid(lons, lats))
plt.contourf(x, y, data)
```

**Note:** The data is in Pascals so you should convert it to hPa/mb (times by `0.01`).

This gives the following plot:
[image: Sandy 2012102800]

---

Here's all the code with modifications for completeness:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import datetime as dt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

def read_var(ncfile, varname):
        fid= nc.Dataset(ncfile, 'r')
        out = fid.variables[varname][:]
        fid.close()
        return out

def prmsltime_from_datetime(wanted_dt):
        time0 = dt.datetime(1800, 01, 01, 0)
        prmsltime = (wanted_dt - time0).days*24
        return prmsltime

psl  = read_var('prmsl.2012.nc', 'prmsl')
lat  = read_var('prmsl.2012.nc', 'lat')
lon  = read_var('prmsl.2012.nc', 'lon')
time = read_var('prmsl.2012.nc', 'time')

date_i_want = dt.datetime(2012, 10, 28, 0)
t = prmsltime_from_datetime(date_i_want)
t_idx = np.where(time == t)[0][0]

lat_top    = np.where(lat <= 52)[0][0]
lat_bottom = np.where(lat >= 24)[0][-1]
lats       = lat[lat_top:lat_bottom]

lon_left  = np.where(lon >= 274)[0][0]
lon_right = np.where(lon <= 306)[0][-1]
lons      = lon[lon_left:lon_right]

m = Basemap(projection='cyl',
            llcrnrlat=lats[-1], urcrnrlat=lats[0],
            llcrnrlon=lons[0],  urcrnrlon=lons[-1],
            resolution='c')

plt.figure()

# convert to mb
data = 0.01*psl[t_idx, lat_top:lat_bottom, lon_left:lon_right]
x,y = m(*np.meshgrid(lons, lats))
plt.contourf(x, y, data)

m.drawcoastlines()
m.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('Latitude')
plt.ylabel('Longitude')
plt.title('SLP on October 28, 2012')
plt.show()
```